# recaptcha error in .net - timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am facing error with recaptha, timeout.

I have specify all keys and just valid() calpcha function on code behind.
It waits for while and time out.

More over, When doing page.Isvalid() with capcha, it is alway false, what should be the reason?

```
  <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" Theme="white" runat="server" PublicKey="6LdwMMgSAAAAALdraGklD-N1Jfr5Fuxq6gyaJMy7"
                                            PrivateKey="6LdwMMgSAAAAAKV6hOjAHdFURCUZ6oS_NmxF8iaD" />



 recaptcha.Validate();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to run without configure your application in IIS, you will get solution

Comment: Amit.  I don't know what you mean.  If I am hosting a site in IIS, how would reConfiguring my site so it's not using IIS anymore help? (that is what I understood from your answer.  Correct me if I'm wrong)  Hosting the site on something besides IIS would be a larger task than just finding a different Captcha solution.

Comment: I down voted your answer, Amit, because it doesn't make sense, is not helpful information, is a lackluster effort of answering a technical question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point this out: you should hide your actual private Recaptcha key. Don't want people seeing that!